# How to set insets inside JScrollPane object?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtree, insets

I have JScrollPane which contains only one instance of JTree. How can I set margin around JTree inside of JScrollPane?

I have such a code

```
tree.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
    JScrollPane scrollerTree = new JScrollPane(tree, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    scrollerTree.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 199));
    scrollerTree.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(16);
```

I want to achieve, that margin would be scrollable with scrollpane content.

Comment: @Andrew: thanks for advice. But I don't understand, I accepted answers almost in each question I have made and also in some question from another users.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Update:** From your updated question I reckon that you are actually after  [`JComponent.setBorder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setBorder%28javax.swing.border.Border%29), example screenshot:

[image: screenshot border]

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    JTree tree = new JTree();
    tree.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
    frame.add(new JScrollPane(tree));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

---

Original answer, if you want a border around the view port, use [`JScrollPane.setViewportBorder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html#setViewportBorder%28javax.swing.border.Border%29):

[image: screenshot viewport border]

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(new JTree());
    scroll.setViewportBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
    frame.add(scroll);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: thank you. I forgot to explain that I want to achieve, that margin would be scrollable with scrollpane content.

Comment: I have already found solution: I have set border to scrollable object: tree.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));

Comment: I already added that example. Good that you got that aswell! :) (Takes a while to get the screenshots up :))